# What happened to Brownian/Hair Particles

Tags: particles, hair

In a Tutorial I am watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ebx2qbBlvh0 Hair Particles are mentioned (15.5 min), *Brownian* to be exact, but I can´t find them in Blender 3.0.
Is that option gone?[image: hair particles] I want to add some hair to my teddy. What I don´t understand is why later on the Hair BDSF is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check *Advanced* under the particle system to enable additional panes like *Rotation* and *Physics*.

The *Hair BSDF* is a pre-made shader containing the components required to recreate the surface response shown by most hair or fur.  Specifically the *Hair BSDF* contains a reflective and a transmissive component.

[Hair BSDF - Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/hair.html#properties)

[Principled Hair BSDF - Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/hair_principled.html)

Comment: Is the Principled Hair BSDF even required for this? I found Brownian and put some numbers in, but no hair appears. I am a bit confused about how to use the BSDF:

Comment: ... should I add it to the node stack of the mesh or create a whole seperate node? In the video it seems like he uses an extra space for the Principled Hair BSDF.

Comment: It's often useful to start a new scene and put a simple hair system on the default cube to toy with settings.  Much less taxing on your system and you can toss everything at the end.

Comment: The particle system should also be set to hair instead of emitter, if you hadn't seen that yet

Comment: Yes, I did that. It´s pretty basic.